# Android: AccountManager returns empty even after login when back pressed or App restarts

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am new to android but facing the problem recently.
On login button pressed the AccountManager is filled with the account Details like this.

```
AccountManager mAccountManager;
    final Account account = new Account(mUsername, Constant.ACCOUNT_TYPE);

    mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, token, null);

    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account,
                ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);
```

but after back pressed or after i restarts the Application when i want to see the account details from:

```
accountManager = AccountManager.get(applicationController.getCurrentActivity());
        accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(packageName);
```

account returns [0], i.e nothing is in it.
Please help me out.

onAuthenticationResult(string,string) function calls finishlogin which store account information

```
public void onAuthenticationResult(String error, String token) {
        // Hide the progress dialog
        // hideProgress();
        if (token != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(token)) {
            {
                finishLogin(token);
                CommonMethods.getInstance().showAppMsg(
                        "Registered Successfully.");

}
}
```

here is the finishLogin function which takes a token and store it in account manager with username

```
protected void finishLogin(String token) {
         account = new Account(mUsername, Constant.ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        if (mRequestNewAccount) {
            mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, token, null);
            // Set contacts sync for this account.
            ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account,
                    ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);
        } else {
            mAccountManager.setPassword(account, mUsername);
        }

        if (Constant.isCampaign) {
            keyarr = new String[] { "token", "imei", "deviceid", "osversion",
                    "modal", "screen_width", "screen_height", "manufacturer",
                    "simcountrycode", "simoperator", "phonetype",
                    "networktype", "gcmregid", "device_type", "app_version",
                    "download_source", "api_version" };
            valuearr = new String[] { token, imei, androidId,
                    String.valueOf(softwareversion), PhoneModel,
                    String.valueOf(divwidth), String.valueOf(divheight),
                    PhoneMANUFACTURER, simcountrycode, simoperator, phonetype,
                    networktype, Constant.NEWGCM_REGD_ID, "ANDROID",
                    "" + Constant.version, "" + Constant.DOWNLOAD_SOURCE,
                    "" + Constant.API_VERSION };

        } else {
            keyarr = new String[] { "token", "imei", "deviceid", "osversion",
                    "modal", "screen_width", "screen_height", "manufacturer",
                    "simcountrycode", "simoperator", "phonetype",
                    "networktype", "gcmregid", "device_type", "app_version",
                    "api_version" };
            valuearr = new String[] { token, imei, androidId,
                    String.valueOf(softwareversion), PhoneModel,
                    String.valueOf(divwidth), String.valueOf(divheight),
                    PhoneMANUFACTURER, simcountrycode, simoperator, phonetype,
                    networktype, Constant.NEWGCM_REGD_ID, "ANDROID",
                    "" + Constant.version, "" + Constant.API_VERSION };

        }

        signUpScreenModel.WriteDeviceInfo(keyarr, valuearr);
        applicationController.handleEvents(
                ApplicationEvents.EVENT_ID_HOME_FRAGMENT, false);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check account logged in main activity in onResume() method if return true you should load data, full code is necessary for other advice.

Comment: I am working on Fragments. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Problem solved. Actually i was removing account some where. My bad.Thank you